# git behind proxy: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout

Tags: git, github

When trying to clone ANY repository via https from github, we get:

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
Cloning into rails...
remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout
```

Our server is behind a proxy.  We have defined http_proxy and https_proxy appropriately.  All other functions are working.

git version is 1.7.5.4

Server is Ubuntu Server 11.04.

Note that since this happens with **EVERY** github repository we've tried, we strongly believe it's not a problem with the refs in the repository.  We've tried such well-known repositories as jquery and rails - if the problem were in those repositories there'd be a lot of people complaining.  I believe strongly the problem is with git and the proxy, but all my googling has not lead to a solution.

As an additional data point, clones seem to work fine if they're http.  It's only the https clones that fail with this error.

Note that I don't think this question is a duplicate, since the other questions with this error focus on problems with the repository - not working with git and a proxy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've stumbled across the solution to this problem via this post:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/185459

The issue is apparently a bug in the libcurl version installed in Ubuntu server 11.04.  Simply running apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls was not sufficient to solve the problem since it simply reported the latest version was already installed.

To solve the problem, I had to manually install the latest libcurl3-gnutls, and two dependencies, as seen below (obviously, after having downloaded them to my system first):

```
sudo dpkg -i libp11-kit0_0.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgnutls26_2.12.14-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcurl3-gnutls_7.22.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: this worked just fine for me, pulled the packages out of the repo for precise.

Comment: Worked here as well, even though I got the following error message: "p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". [Reported to Ubuntu.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/940431)

Comment: dpkg: error processing libcurl3-gnutls_7.22.0-3ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386) . Cool. Could you post the 32bit solutions too. I actually used the Alexey Romanov's solution.

Comment: I've just managed to install libp11-kit0_0.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb and it fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

the packages noted above can be found here:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/amd64/libp11-kit0/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/amd64/libgnutls26/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/amd64/libcurl3-gnutls/download

I used these versions and was able to use git behind a proxy without issue:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libp11-kit0_0.10-1_amd64.deb libgnutls26_2.12.14-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb libcurl3-gnutls_7.22.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 9):

A workaround found at the linked Ubuntu bug:

> add the following to ~/.gitconfig or /etc/gitconfig

```
# Workaround for bug when using SSL and HTTP proxy (LP #940431)
[url "http://"]
 insteadOf = "https://"
```

No longer necessary starting with 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be:

regressing libcurl3 from 7.21.0 to 7.19.5.

Download it from here:

amd64:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/30289951/libcurl3-gnutls_7.19.5-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

i386:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/30287711/libcurl3-gnutls_7.19.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb