# Unable to clone using Git over HTTP

Tags: git, http, version-control, proxy, kde-plasma

I am behind  a proxy that does not allow the use of git://. So I need to checkout using git over http. For this, I have already set my proxy in git using,

```
git config --global http.proxy http://172.30.0.16:3128
```

However, I am able to clone only a few repos, while on others I am getting an error.
For example:

```
git clone http://github.com/jcnetdev/yubnub.git
```

works perfectly fine, while

```
https://github.com/ferhatelmas/InterviewStreet.git
```

this returns the following error

```
Cloning into InterviewStreet...
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

On running 
`git clone http://anongit.kde.org/calligra` I get the following error

```
Cloning into calligra...
error: The requested URL returned error: 502 while accessing http://anongit.kde.org/calligra/info/refs
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: Well, in that case, the clone from KDE should have worked as well.

Comment: Cloning InterviewStreet worked fine for me.  Have you set up your ssh keys properly?

Comment: @Saurav: I tried cloning interview street over HTTP and it worked. Problem seems to be with cloning Calligra from KDE. I cannot use ssh as I am behind a proxy that allows only HTTP.

Comment: I can't clone the kde one either. It appears that the problem is exactly what the error states; their site isn't responding.

Comment: @BrianRoach: thanks for checking, I shall ask KDE about this problems in the IRC and add a tag "KDE" to this question.

Comment: @ard - for your other issue ... googling the error produced http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403792/git-behind-proxy-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the KDE git hosting which had only partial HTTP support.

Comment: so what is the solution then?

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling git solved the problem for me for the same issue